# React Hooks setTimeout and clearTimeout

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I read the 'Using the Effect Hook' doc but I'm still having a hard time cleaning up side effects from `useEffect` hook. Specifically I have this class component, and I'd like to learn how it can be converted to function component using `useEffect` hook.

```
class Alert extends PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleSetTimeout()
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.handleClearTimeout()
    this.handleSetTimeout()
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.handleClearTimeout()
  }

  handleSetTimeout = () => {
    const { alert: { id, ttl }, handlePopAlert } = this.props
    if (!ttl) return
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => handlePopAlert(id), ttl)
  }

  handleClearTimeout = () => {
    if (!this.timeout) return
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    this.timeout = null
  }

  render() { return (...) }
}
```

Comment: Dan Abramov recently published blog article exactly on that: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.

Comment: btw you know you are not required to clear `this.timeout` since `clearTimeout` allows you to pass already stopped timer's id

Comment: Ohhhh gotcha :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function passed to `useEffect` may return a clean-up function.The clean-up function runs before the component is removed from the UI to prevent memory leaks. Additionally, if a component renders multiple times (as they typically do), the previous effect is cleaned up before executing the next effect.

In your case since the `handlePopAlert` function needs to be called based on the id passed from props, the effect needs to run whenever the `id, ttl` is changed for which you pass the **second argument to `useEffect` as the id and ttl**

```
const Alert = (props) => {
  const { alert: { id, ttl }, handlePopAlert } = this.props
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
       handlePopAlert(id)
    }, ttl)
    return () => {
       clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  }, [id, ttl]);

  return (...)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Docs are great but I needed to see more examples.